# Bootstrap move one element below another in mobile devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am having the following layout for my website and is built using responsive Bootstrap.

[image: Page layout]

Now when I view it in a mobile device it comes in the following order:

1. HEADER
2. FORM
3. PROMOTIONS
4. INFORMATION
5. FOOTER

However, I don't want the promotions feature to come below the form for a mobile device. Instead I need the information section to come after the form and then the promotions section and then the footer.

Is there a way to achieve this using `@media` query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, if you can control height of promotion block, this example can help you:

http://jsfiddle.net/vXb95/

```
<div id="header" class="bordered">header</div>

<div class="content">
    <div id="form" class="bordered">form</div>    
    <div id="info" class="bordered">infomation</div>
    <div id="promotion" class="bordered" >promotion</div>
</div>

<div id="footer" class="bordered">footer</div>



.bordered{
    border:1px solid #333;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.content{
    position:relative;
}

#form{
    margin-right: 35%;
}

#promotion{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 30%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    #promotion{
        position: static;
        width: auto;
    }

    #form{
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q65kK/)

A dumb way to do this is by duplicating the promotional features part and showing/hiding them by media queries:

### HTML

```
<div id="header">header</div>
<div id="form">form</div>
<div id="promotion">promotion</div>
<div id="info">info</div>
<div id="promotion2">promotion</div>
<div id="footer">footer</div>
```

### CSS

```css
#promotion2 { display: none; }

@media (max-width: 400px) {
    #promotion { display: none; }
    #promotion2 { display: block; }
}
```

Comment: Instead of media queries it would be simpler to just use the appropriate Bootstrap [responsive class](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) to show/hide each div

Comment: @koala_dev can you give an example for your comment. I don't  get it completely